# Load JSON file, error undefined

Tags: javascript, json, load

I'm trying to load a JSON file that I'll use as constants file, but I'm always getting the error undefined, could any one help?

Here is the code:

```
function loadJsonFile(filePath){
 $.getJSON(filePath, function(Mydata) {
    alert(Mydata.length);
    return Mydata;
    })
error(function() { alert("error"); 
});
```

The structure of constants file is:

```
{
    "var1":"v1",
    "var2":"v2"
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Where are you getting error undefined, what line? also you are missing a dot . between `)` and `error` is that a typo from typing this question or is it really missing the dot

Comment: make sure the file path you are giving is correct, let us know what error you are getting in network tab of developers tool

Comment: @PatrickEvans  it was an error while I was typing the question, i get the error when I call my function :  var data= loadJsonFile('./constants.json'); alert(data["var1"]);

Comment: @vinayakj yes the path is correct, i get as an error : " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'var1' of undefined

Comment: you need to alert in success callback, you are alerting it before even you get the response. not like this var data= loadJsonFile('./constants.json'); alert(data["var1"]);

Comment: @vinayakj same error :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @yatikamika try my answer given below

Comment: @PatrickEvans is right, yatika you either need to make AJAX synchronuos to return the response or else you need to have callback function to do your work, you cant return response in asynchrnous as it its name indicates.

Comment: @vinayakj "Make AJAX synchronous" is never the answer

Comment: I must pass by doStuff function? I only wanna get the list of varsin my main function

Comment: Then pass main as callback function instead of doStuff, doStuff is just a placeholder function I wrote. you can use like loadJsonFile('url', yourMainFunction);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadJsonFile(filePath, callback){
       $.getJSON(filePath)
        .success(function(Mydata) {
              callback(data);
       })
       .fail(function() { alert("error")}); ;
});

function doStuff(data){
  alert(data.var1)
}

loadJsonFile('url', doStuff);
```

Comment: I can't call it in my main function :( could you please help

Comment: Please create a jsFIddle with your all code, so then I could modify and give it to you

Comment: Thank you @vinayakj , i considered updates and it works. Btw, i'm seeking for someone who can do a code review for a small part ofmy code,could you please accept my request?

Comment: Thank you , could you please make a sign at yatikamika [AT] gmail [DOT] com apparently I can't contact you here :/

Answer (score 0):

For a call to loadJsonFile to return a value, the return statement has to be placed outwith the $.getJSON() success callback function. There's also some syntax errors in the failure handler, and .fail() should be used instead as [.error() is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```
function loadJsonFile(filePath) {
    var data = null;
    $.getJSON(filePath, function(Mydata) {
        alert(Mydata.length);
        data = Mydata;
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
    return data;
}
```

Comment: the return I can't use it later in my main funciton ! could you please help

Answer (score -2):

Two things:
 1. Are you missing a JSON.parse() ?

```
Mydata = JSON.parse(Mydata); // we parse it here
alert(Mydata.length);
return Mydata;
```

2. Remember a valid json object must be between comillas ("|'). If you do

   JSON.parse({ "var1":"v1", "var2":"v2" });

you would get error. Correct way is:

```
JSON.parse('{ "var1":"v1", "var2":"v2" }');
```

Comment: @oxacarga I added JSON.Parse but always the same error :( for the (') i'm putting directly the filepath, so no need to put it no?

Comment: its getJSON method, JSON.parse is implicit